# Need to parse Connection String in XML using Xpath

Tags: xpath

Below is the sample XML I have,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig
        PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN"
        "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">
<sqlMapConfig>

    <settings useStatementNamespaces="true"/>

    <transactionManager type="JDBC">
        <dataSource type="SIMPLE" connectionString="DataSource=server;name=sampledatasource;Password=abc">

        </dataSource>
      </transactionManager>

    <sqlMap resource="user.xml"/>

</sqlMapConfig>
```

I need to get the Password from the above xml. Used //dataSource/@connectionString , but this is giving me entire connectionString as "DataSource=server;name=sampledatasource;Password=abc" But I need to parse "Password" alone from the connectionString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below xpath.

```
substring-after(//dataSource/@connectionString,'Password=')
```

[image]